# Getting null when trying to return only single object and not array in graphql for neo4j db

Tags: neo4j, graphql, apollo-server

I want to return a single object(not array).The graphql server is returning null when i try to return single object.But seems to work fine while trying to return an array.

**Here is my schema example:**

```
type Author{
     authorID: String
     label: String 
     posts: [Post]
   }

 type Post {
      postID: String
      label: String
      author: Author
 }

type Query {
       getAuthorById (authorID: String!): Author #-> this does not work
       getAuthorById (authorID: String!): [Author] #-> this works
 }
```

But when I try to run this query "**getAuthorById (authorID: String!)**",I am getting the following result:

```
 {
  "data": {
    "getAuthorById": {
            "label": null,
            "authorID": null
   }
 }
```

However,it seems to work only if i try to return an array (when I try to change the schema for type query like this):

```
type Query {
      getAuthorById (authorID: String!): [Author]
 }
```

**Here is my resolver.js:**

```
Query: {
 getAuthorById(_, params) {

   let session = driver.session();

   let query = `MATCH (a:Author{ authorID: $authorID})  RETURN a ;`

      return session.run(query, params)

     .then( result => {
       return result.records.map( record => {
         return record.get("a").properties
       }
     )
   }
  )
 },

}
```

What I need is to return a single object like this:
**getAuthorById (authorID: String!): Author**

// Instead of array like this-> getAuthorById (authorID: String!): [Author]

**so,could someone let me know what am i doing wrong here ?** All I need is to return single object and not array .... Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is in your resolver, specifically you are returning the result of `result.records.map()` from the resolver. `map()` evaluates to an Array (applying the inner function to each element of `result` in this case.

Instead you can just grab the first `Record` in the `Result` stream:

```
.then( result => {
   return result.records[0].get("a").properties
   }
 )
```

Comment: Thanks @William, it worked...Lastly, could you please point out any specific link where I could learn more regarding these properties and neo4j documentation cause I have read most of the neo4j blogs, but still never got a hold of useful insight as you provided. Thanks again !

Comment: Great! Docs for Neo4j JavaScript driver are here: http://neo4j.com/docs/api/javascript-driver/current/